# connecting an aws elastic beanstalk ruby on rails app to an aws postgres rds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

i have a ruby rails app i deployed to aws with elastic beanstalk, i need to connect it to aws rds
heres my database.yml

```
 production:  
  adapter: postgresql 
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %> #  
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>  
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>  
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```

i am able to connect to my aws db from pgadmin but ones i deploy that database.yml
i get this error

```
+ cd /var/app/ondeck
  + su -s /bin/bash -c 'bundle exec /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/scripts/check-for-rake-task.rb db:migrate' webapp
  `/home/webapp` is not a directory.
  Bundler will use `/tmp/bundler20200525-23041-9y70lv23041' as your home directory temporarily.
  + '[' false = true ']'
  + su -s /bin/bash -c 'leader_only bundle exec rake db:migrate' webapp
  `/home/webapp` is not a directory.
  Bundler will use `/tmp/bundler20200525-23045-1bhxksf23045' as your home directory temporarily.
  rake aborted!
  PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on host "aapujs6mg3rasw.cxytyfiwlama.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (172.31.39.107) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 3306?
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
  Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Comment: Ising `3306` port for mysql?

Comment: set `ENV` value for `RDS_PORT` as `5432` if you are using PostgreSQL `3306` if you are using mysql

Comment: i have the RDS_PORT = 5432, im using postgres